# Security issue while implementing java Google Drive API with Domino XPages

Tags: java, security, google-drive-api, xpages

I am implementing the Google Drive API using the java jars. I started with the sample DriveCommandLine.java found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java .
The XPage throws the following:
Error while calling java constructor ... (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException).
not allowed to access members in class class java.util.AbstractMap

I understand that the Google java code uses reflection, which is not allowed by the default Lotus Domino java.policy file. I tested changing the default permission to:
permission java.security.AllPermission;

which solved the security issue.

My concern is now, not to leave the java.policy file with an open default permission. 
I was not able to find the documentation for the java.policy specs...
Is there a way to narrow this permission to the specific code which needs it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#ReflectPermission . I believe the one you want is java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission . Understand that there are security implications in setting this.

Answer (score 6):

Please try

```
grant {
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

This should allow the reflection for your java classes.

Alternativly you can restrict the policy settings for a single database only:

```
grant codeBase "xspnsf://server:0/path/to/your/db.nsf/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

In this setting you have to change the path to your database (by replacing the */path/to/your/db.nsf/* only, not the *server:0*).

Instead of giving all permissions to the single database, you can restrict it to the ReflectPermission too.

Comment: grant {
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
did not work. I guess it is not enough to cover for the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: using:
grant codeBase "xspnsf:server:0/test/GoogleDrive.nsf/-" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};
did not work either. I guess I am missing punctuation...
Where can I find documentation on java.policy file syntax, applied to XPages?

Comment: @fenaten: It seems that you have forgotten the slashes for the xspnsf protocol (*xspnsf://*) You can find the documentation in the *Portable Command Guide*.