# Lotus Domino Java security issue using Google GSON

Tags: java, xpages, gson, lotus-domino

Attempting to use the [Google GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in a java method which is kicked off via an Xpage.

I can create the gson object without a problem but then when attempting to call `gson.toJson(jsonObj)` I'm getting the following error:

> HTTP JVM: java.lang.SecurityException: not allowed to access members
>   in class class java.util.HashMap
>
> HTTP JVM:  at
>   lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
>
> HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:112)
>
> HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:419)

The code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> jsonObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
jsonObj.put("apiStatus", apiStatus);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(jsonObj);  // Exception thrown on this line
```

I've seen [something similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088051/security-issue-while-implementing-java-google-drive-api-with-domino-xpages) but I've implemented both suggested policy changes, neither appear to have any effect:

> grant {
>       permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks"; };
>
> grant codeBase "xspnsf://server:0/path/to/your/db.nsf/-" {
>       permission java.security.AllPermission; };

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like updating the security file on server file system you can avoid using gson and replace it with xpages own JSON serializer see my blog post here:

http://blog.tcl-digitrade.com/blogs/tcl-digitrade-blog.nsf/dx/28.01.2013090943DMABL6.htm

Comment: The package that comes with Domino after 8.5.2 (I think) is [com.ibm.commons.util.io.json](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/commons/util/io/json/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is almost the same exception:

[Java Permission for Jackson on Domino XPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759633/java-permission-for-jackson-on-domino-xpage)

Use

```
grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
```

It should work with that. If you don't want to keep it this open then check the syntax of your `grant codeBase`:

> In this setting you have to change the path to your database (by
>   replacing the /path/to/your/db.nsf/ only, **not the server:0**).

Comment: Thanks Panu, do I need the dash after the final slash?

Comment: I have never used this but the dash is there in all instructions so I believe yes.